# Use find to find a directory and move it to a different path

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, find, mv

I have hundreds of thousands of files in hundreds of directories.

An example directory structure is

```
./main/foo1/bar/*
./main/foo2/bar/*
./main/foo3/bar/*
./main/foo1/ran/*
./main/foo2/ran/*
```

For folders that have 'bar' directories, I want to move contents to following structure.

```
./secondary/bar/foo1/*
./secondary/bar/foo2/*
./secondary/bar/foo3/*
```

Can this be accomplished using find and mv?

Comment: are the foo and bar directorys always in the same depth?

Comment: Yes, the depth is consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some little script to achieve this:

```bsh
# Set the variables
main="./main"
secondary="./secondary"
foo_depth=3
bar_depth=4
bar_name="bar"

# let * match hidden files
shopt -s dotglob

# Loop through find (which is declared after done)
while IFS= read -r dir; do

    # Read names of foo dir
    foo=$(printf '%s' "$dir" | cut -d'/' -f $foo_depth)

    # mkdir target and mv dir there
    target="${secondary}/${bar_name}/${foo}"
    mkdir -p "$target"
    mv "$dir"/* "$target"

    # as you mv the content of bar dir only,
    # you may want to remove the full path to that folder
    # rmdir -p will do that without deleting anything that is not empty,
    # we can ignore the "failed to remove" messages.
    [ $? = 0 ] && rmdir -p "${dir}"

done < <(find "$main" -type d -name "$bar_name")

# Turn off dotglob
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: Thanks but my apologies since I messed up a bit. The 'sub' directory is not alone there and is a mix of files and folders that I intend to move. I've edited the question. Can you please edit your script? Really appreciated.

Comment: I made an update.